# How to group objects with specific key in javaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I want to do a grouping for JavaScript object as age.My JSON is

```
var jsonObj=[{"name":"john","age":23},{"name":"mark","age":25},{"name":"jeni","age":21}]`
```

I want to be the group result like here.

```
[23:{"name":"john","age":23},25:{"name":"mark","age":25},21:{"name":"jeni","age":21}]
```

Please help me to get a result, I try with `map` and `filter` but did not get the result.

Comment: what do you do with two objects with same age?

Comment: poll is gone in the process :(

Comment: @NinaScholz yes i fogot that it should come as array.

Comment: @Kaddath sorry for wrong input, see the edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to group the objects. Because there can multiple people with the same age, collect them into an array under the age property:

```js
var jsonObj=[{"name":"john","age":23},{"name":"mark","age":25},{"name":"poll","age":23},{"name":"jeni","age":21}];

var result = jsonObj.reduce(function(r, o) {
  r[o.age] || (r[o.age] = []); // if the age key doesn't exist, set it to be an array
  
  r[o.age].push(o); // push the object into the array

  return r;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Or the fancy ES6 one liner version:

```js
var jsonObj=[{"name":"john","age":23},{"name":"mark","age":25},{"name":"poll","age":23},{"name":"jeni","age":21}];

var result = jsonObj.reduce((r, o) => ((r[o.age] || (r[o.age] = [])).push(o), r), {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could take the hash table as result. Then loop and create new arrays for new keys. Later push the object.

```js
var data = [{ name: "john", age: 23 }, { name: "mark", age: 25 }, { name: "poll", age: 23 }, { name: "jeni", age: 21 }],
    result = {};

data.forEach(o => (result[o.age] = result[o.age] || []).push(o));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [underscore js](http://underscorejs.org/) to solve this problem.
Add underscore js first
`<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js' ></script>`
 then you can simply get the result.
`var result=_.indexBy(jsonObj, 'age');`

Comment: How can you handle with the object with two same age?

Comment: then you can use `_.groupBy(jsonObj, 'age')`

Comment: Yes. It is a simple way with underscore js. thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You can try it :

```
var jsonObj = [{ "name": "john", "age": 23 }, { "name": "mark", "age": 25 }, { "name": "poll", "age": 23 }, { "name": "jeni", "age": 21 }];
let result = {};
jsonObj.forEach(item => {
    if(result.hasOwnProperty(item.age)) {
        let arr = [];
        if(Array.isArray(result[item.age])) {
            result[item.age].push(item);
        } else {
            result[item.age] = [result[item.age], item];
        }
    } else {
        result[item.age] = item;
    }
});
console.log(result)
```

Comment: in your `jsonObj` two object has same ages it should come as array

Comment: ou , I  understand you